# Replace two forward slashes with one using escape?

Tags: replace, escape

I am new to VI.  How do you replace two forward slashes with one globally?

I did:

```
:%s/\//
```

and

```
:%/\//\/g
```

Those don't work as desired.

**Example or Goal**

```
//This is good//because it//works;

//on every//Line it//is used one;
```

**Desired output**

```
/This is good/because it/works;

/on every/Line it/is used one;
```

Comment: You're missing a final / on your second command, but it's probably easier to use a different delimiter: s|//|/|g

Comment: While I'm always happy to mark questions as duplicate I don't think this one is a duplicate of the one linked by @Quasímodo . Sure the usage is the same but if OP doesn't know that `:s` can take different separators they would never find the other question. Plus this question focuses on substituting `/`s while my question focuses on the general usage of `:s` with `!`... So I wouldn't close this one as duplicate.

Comment: @Quasímodo yes that's much closer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command you are trying to use is the following:

```
%s/\/\//\//g
%             The range: All lines in buffer
 s            the substitution command
  /    /  /   the separators of the substitution command
   \/\/       in the matching pattern you need to escape both slashes
        \/    you also need to escape the slash in the replacement string
           g  and finally the flag to match all occurrences in the line
```

However as the comments said in this case you should use a different separator for the substitution command this way you don't need to escape the `/`. For example this would do the job:

```
%s;//;/;g
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the great answers.  A different separator is easier.  This one with the awesome breakdown of parts is exactly what I was looking for.   I wanted to know how to accomplish this using the escape option.